# Is it possible to inherit from class with Generic in Python?

Tags: python, generics, inheritance, descendant, python-3.5

Since Python 3.5 you can use Generics and other interesting stuff described in [PEP-0484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/). 
I tried that and here's a code I have:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Optional
...

_T = TypeVar('T')
_S = TypeVar('S')


class Pool(Generic[_S, _T]):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.pool = dict()

    ... getters and setters here...
```

This code works perfectly and does what is expected. Then I decided to extend this class to make some additional work. That's how I did that:

```
class PoolEx(Pool[_S, _T]):

    ARGUMENTS = []

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print("self=", self, self.__class__.__bases__)
        super(PoolEx, self).__init__()
        self.arguments_pool = dict()

    ... other code here ...
```

To test `Pool` class I created `MyPool` which looked like this:

```
class MyPool(Pool[str, Hello]):
    pass
```

Then I put something like `mypool = MyPool()` and it worked fine. Once I implemented `PoolEx`, I've updated `MyPool` to this:

```
class MyPool(PoolEx[str, Hello]):
    ARGUMENTS = ['name', 'surname']
```

And tried to do the same thing: `mypool = MyPool()`. Unfortunately I got:

```
self= <__main__.MyPool object at 0x1068644e0> (__main__.PoolEx[str, __main__.Hello],)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/8bitjoey/.../utils/pool.py", line 141, in <module>
    mypool = MyPool()
  File "/Users/8bitjoey/.../utils/pool.py", line 52, in __init__
    super(PoolEx, self).__init__()
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

As you can see, I also put `self.__class__.__bases` to the log. When I tried to test `isinstance(self, PoolEx)` and similar with `issubclass`, I got False. Same as `super()` verifications.

Is it something with my code or such classes can't have descendants? And if I still want to have PoolEx I have to use composition rather than inheritance.

Comment: Since this is Python3 you can use the shorter form: `super().__init__()`. Does that work?

Comment: Nope. It was how I implemented that first. Then I was playing with different calls to super and in the code above is one of variants.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Using `super()` worked for me when retyping the class itself did not. Why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, just for the record, I have just run your code on Python 3.8.10, and I've got no errors. It runned perfectly.
Then I've pulled the docker image python:3.5.0 from Docker Hub and run it again, and then I've got your exact same error:

```
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

So it seems to have been and issue with the first implementations of such features, which have already been fixed in latest versions.

Here follows the file I used for testing, in case anyone will ever be interested in reproduce any similar errors:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Optional

_T = TypeVar('T')
_S = TypeVar('S')

class Pool(Generic[_S, _T]):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.pool = dict()

class PoolEx(Pool[_S, _T]):
    ARGUMENTS = []

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print("self=", self, self.__class__.__bases__)
        super(PoolEx, self).__init__()
        self.arguments_pool = dict()

class MyPool(Pool[str, int]):
    pass

mypool = MyPool()

class MyPool(PoolEx[str, int]):
    ARGUMENTS = ['name', 'surname']

mypool2 = MyPool()
```